# Переходы Activity android

Tags: java, android, activity

Здрaвcтвуйте! Как сделать, чтобы приложение не запоминало все переходы активити. Т.е если я сделаю 10 переходов между активностями, то для того чтобы выйти из приложения, нажать "назад" не 10 раз, а 2 раза допустим. Пишу на Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы приложение ничего не запоминало то можно в файле `AndroidManifest.xml` в активности которую вы хотите исключить из истории добавить флаг:

```
<activity
    android:name=".AnyActivity"
    android:noHistory="true" />
```

так же довольно действенным способом является вызов `finish()` сразу после `startActivity()`. Так же при переходе на новую активность можно очищать стек активностей программно добавив флаг:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
```

чтобы покинуть активность на второй клик кнопки назад можно использовать данную конструкцию в нужной вам активности ([источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430805/clicking-the-back-button-twice-to-exit-an-activity)):

```
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;                       
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```